# simulate VHDL Half Adder but got Errors

Tags: vhdl

I'm learning vhdl and trying to design half adder in vivado. I wrote below code for both design and testbench and try to simulate it but got errors. Any support please! Also I would appreciate any useful links that I can learn from.

***errors log:***

```
    syntax error near sum [half_adder.vhd:44]

    syntax error near carry [half_adder.vhd:45]

    unit behavioral ignored due to previous errors [half_adder.vhd:41]
```

*Here is the design code:*
**half_adder.vhdl**

```
   library IEEE;

   use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
   entity half_adder is
   Port ( 
       x : in STD_LOGIC;
       y : in STD_LOGIC;
       sum : out STD_LOGIC;
       carry : out STD_LOGIC
     ); 

Line 41 -- end half_adder;

architecture Behavioral of half_adder is 
Line 44 --   begin
Line 45 -- assign sum<=x xor y; 
assign carry<= x and y;

end Behavioral;
```

*Here is the testbench code:*
**ha_tb.vhdl**

```
 library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity ha_tb is
end ha_tb;

 architecture Behavioral of ha_tb is
 component halfa is
 port(
      x : in STD_LOGIC;
  Line 41--    y : in STD_LOGIC;
      sum : out STD_LOGIC;
      carry : out STD_LOGIC
 Line 44--    );
 Line 45--  end component; 
 signal input1,input2: in STD_LOGIC;
 signal outputs,outputc: in STD_LOGIC;

 begin
 HA:halfa port map (x=>input1,y=>input2,sum=>outputs,carry=>outputc);
 stimulus_proc:process
 begin
x<='0';
y<='0';
wait for 20ns;
 x<='0';
   y<='1';
   wait for 20ns;
    x<='1';
      y<='0';
      wait for 20ns;
       x<='1';
         y<='1';
         wait;
  end process;

 end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The `assign` keyword exists in Verilog, but not in VHDL. The assignments should be as follows: `sum <= x xor y;`, `carry <= x and y;`.

Comment: In addition, your line number annotations don't reflect the error message line numbers accurately. Your testbench doesn't have a component specification mapping halfa to half adder, either (change halfa to half_adder both places). The signal declarations in ha_tb are not interface declarations, they don't require mode (e.g. `in`). The VHDL standard requires a separator between adjacent abstract literals and identifiers (e.g. `20ns` should be `20 ns`) whether Modelsim enforces the requirement or not. In process stimulus_proc x, y assignments should be to input1 and input2 respectively instead.

Comment: An additional `wait for 20 ns;` before the final `wait;` would allow you to see the results of the last input1 and input2 changes in a waveform display.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. I did the changes but now getting another error below,although I closed the program and reopened it again but still getting the same error.

Comment: #error message(Unable to remove previous simulation file. Please check if you have another instance of this simulation running on your system, terminate it and then recompile your design).

Comment: Your error messages aren't complete enough to identify a specific tool, the one immediately above appears to be from ISIM.  Never having used it, see [AR# 33426](https://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/33426.html) found by googling. Tool specific issues are beyond the remit of [tag:vhdl].

Answer (score -1):

Check with this code, assign function you can use only Verilog in vhdl assign function not supported

```
library IEEE;

   use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
   entity half_adder is
   Port ( 
       x : in STD_LOGIC;
       y : in STD_LOGIC;
       sum : out STD_LOGIC;
       carry : out STD_LOGIC
     ); 

Line 41 -- end half_adder;

architecture Behavioral of half_adder is 
begin
sum<=x xor y; 
carry<= x and y;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Please explain what you are doing. Don't just give corrected code. Stackoverflow is supposed to be a source of information, not a correcting service. By the way: if you give corrected code, provide a full working example. This has commented lines and improper indentation.

Comment: Sorry, in that code they used "assign" statement but in vhdl code assign statement is not synthesizable instead of assign a <= b & c use a <= b and c